# How can I emulate constructor and destructor behavior (for particular data types) in C

Tags: c++, c, constructor, destructor

I have a C (nested) structure that I would like to automagically initialize and destroy in my code.

I am compiling with GCC (4.4.3) on Linux. I am vaguely aware of GCC function attributes constructor and destructor, but the construction/destruction they provide seem to relate to the entire program (i.e. before main() is called etc).

I want to be able to have different init/cleanup funcs for different data types - is this C++ like behaviour something that I can emulate using POC?

I have included the C++ tag because this is really C++ behaviour I am trying to emulate in C.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you cannot just use C++?

Comment: There could be many reason. May be the environment he is working does not have C++ compiler

Answer (score 12):

There's no way to do this automatically, at least not in any portable manner. In C you'd typically have functions that work somewhat like constructors and destructors — they (de)allocate memory and (de)initialize fields —, except they have to be called explicitly:

```
typedef struct{} MyStruct;
MyStruct *MyStruct_New(void);
void MyStruct_Free(MyStruct *obj);
```

The language was simply not designed for this and you shouldn't try to force it, imo. If you want to have automatic destruction, you shouldn't be using C.

Comment: Well, once can (and probably should) add "de-/initialize only" functions (`void MyStruct_Init(MyStruct *); void MyStruct_Finalize(MyStruct *);`) for working on the stack or with pre-allocated memory (`...New/...Free` then become `MyStruct *p = malloc(sizeof(*p)); MyStruct_Init(p); return p;` and `MyStruct_Finalize(p); free(p);`). But generally, yeah.

Comment: @delnan: sure, you can add as many initializer/cleanup functions as you like. The point is that there is no way to force these functions to be called automatically when you create or destroy an object.

Comment: @jalf I get that point, agree and gave +1. I'm just trying to contribute further while we're at it :)

Comment: you are mixing up constructor/destructor versus `new`/`delete`, these are different things

Comment: @Jens I'm not mixing them up. This is what replaces constructors and destructors in C.

Comment: @JensGustedt +1 for your comment. A ctor can do much more than simply alloc - which is relevant in my case, where I have to initialize a lot of struct fields.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli `MyStruct_New` doesn't just allocate (why not just use `malloc` then?), it's also supposed to initialize the data. Also, `MyStruct_Free` doesn't free just the struct itself, but its members as well, if needed.

Answer (score 9):

#### #define your way through the problem...

As pointed out by previous authors there is no automatic way of doing what you are asking, which sadly is kind of obvious since C doesn't have any way of doing true OOP.

But a programmer can always hack him or herself through any kind of obstacle.. At the end of this post I wrote you a sample hack to circumvent the problem.

There are methods of cleaning up the macro provided, though it won't be as portable.

---

- *C99 implementation:* http://ideone.com/9XcCt
- *C89 implementation:* http://ideone.com/WYrjU

---

#### - C99 implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

...

```
#define SCOPIFY(TYPE,NAME, ...) { \
  ctor_ ## TYPE(& NAME); \
  __VA_ARGS__ \
  dtor_ ## TYPE(& NAME); \
} (void)0
```

...

```
typedef struct {
  int * p;
} Obj;

void
ctor_Obj(Obj* this) {
   this->p = malloc(sizeof (int));
  *this->p = 123;

  fprintf(stderr, "Obj::ctor, (this -> %p)\n", (void*)this);
}

void
dtor_Obj(Obj* this) {
  free(this->p);

  fprintf(stderr, "Obj::dtor, (this -> %p)\n", (void*)this);
}
```

...

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Obj o1, o2;
    
  SCOPIFY(Obj, o1, 
    fprintf (stderr, "  o1.p -> %d\n", *o1.p);

    SCOPIFY(Obj, o2, 
      int a, b;

      fprintf(stderr, "  o2.p -> %d\n", *o2.p);
      (*o1.p) += (*o2.p);
    );  

    fprintf(stderr, "  o1.p -> %d\n", *o1.p);
  );  

  return 0;
}
```

**output** (http://ideone.com/WYrjU)

```
Obj::ctor, (this -> 0xbf8f05ac)
  o1.p -> 123
Obj::ctor, (this -> 0xbf8f05a8)
  o2.p -> 123
Obj::dtor, (this -> 0xbf8f05a8)
  o1.p -> 246
Obj::dtor, (this -> 0xbf8f05ac)
```

Comment: +1 For interesting solution, but I don't think it's really worth it. You still have to manage the scope manually (you have to use the macro), so you haven't really gained much.

Comment: @PaulManta Yeah, I'm mostly goofing around to be honest.. but since C isn't a language designed to handle OOP in the sense that OP is asking for there isn't much to be done.

Answer (score 2):

From what you write, I figure that you know already how to write init and destroy functions that eventually use their counterparts for individual parts recursively.

Yes, there is no standard mechanism in C that would allow for something like automatic construction or destruction.

Construction can be somewhat replace by writing an initializer macro. Designated initializers come handy for that

```
#define TOTO_INITIALIZER(TUTU_PARAM, TATA_PARAM) \
{                                                \
 .tata_member = TATA_INITIALIZER(TATA_PARAM),    \
 .tutu_member = TUTU_INITIALIZER(TUTU_PARAM),    \
}
```

since they make that such code robust against reordering of members.

For destructors there is nothing that can be coupled to a variable or data type. The only thing I know of what is possible is scope based resource management that in C you can implement through hidden `for`-scope local variables.

Answer (score 1):

There's no default way to have a function automatically called when you create a struct. Here's an example of a creation and initialisation function set for a certain type of struct:

```
// Simple struct that holds an ID number and a file pointer.
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    FILE *data;
} Datum;

// Function to create a Datum from a given file.
Datum *create_datum(const char *fname)
{
    // Create Datum object.
    Datum *d = (Datum*)malloc(sizeof(Datum));
    // malloc may return NULL if we're out of memory.
    if(d)
    {
        // Initialise ID to something.
        d->id = 0;
        // Open filename passed.
        d->data = fopen(fname, "r");
    }
    return d;
}

// Function to safely destroy a Datum. This function takes a pointer-pointer so
// that it can set the pointer to NULL after deleting the object. Saves you
// from dangling pointers.
void destroy_datum(Datum **dp)
{
    if(!dp)
        return;
    // Get a plain pointer for convenience
    Datum *d = *dp;
    if(d)
    {
        // Close the file.
        fclose(d->data);
        // Delete the object.
        free(d);
        // Set the pointer to NULL.
        *dp = NULL;
    }
}

// Now use these functions:
int main(void)
{
    Datum *datum = create_datum("test.txt");
    if(datum)
    {
        // Do some things!
    }
    destroy_datum(&datum);
    // datum is now equal to NULL.
}
```

Hope that helps! Like Homunculus has said, C isn't a great language if you need to do a lot of this sort of stuff - but sometimes you just want to abstract away the process of creating a struct, as well as cleaning it up. This is especially helpful in modular design, where a module can provide the `create_` and `destroy_` interface functions, and hide the actual implementation of those.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see the `gcc` tag, but since the original poster mention explicit use of GCC constructor/destructor attributes:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconstructor_007d-function-attribute-2500

I'd like to point out that there is also the `cleanup` attribute:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bcleanup_007d-variable-attribute-3486

> `cleanup (cleanup_function)`
> The cleanup attribute runs a function when
> the variable goes out of scope. This attribute can only be applied to
> auto function scope variables; it may not be applied to parameters or
> variables with static storage duration. The function must take one
> parameter, a pointer to a type compatible with the variable. The
> return value of the function (if any) is ignored. If -fexceptions is
> enabled, then cleanup_function is run during the stack unwinding that
> happens during the processing of the exception. Note that the cleanup
> attribute does not allow the exception to be caught, only to perform
> an action. It is undefined what happens if cleanup_function does not
> return normally.